# Define a next_in_line method on Array that takes the element at the beginning of the array and puts it at the end

Tags: arrays, ruby

Here's the instructions on what I'm supposed to do.

> Define a `next_in_line` method on Array that takes the element at the beginning of the array and puts it at the end. Hint: remember, `Array#shift` removes the first element, and `Array#push` adds an element to the end.

I've tried a dozen variations but nothing seems to work. Here's what I thought would work:

```
class Array
  define_method(:next_in_line) do
    new_array = self.shift()
    new_array = new_array.push()
  end
end
```

Pardon my non-programmer-speak syntax, but here's what I thought I was doing:

1. Define the class of the method (array).
2. Define the method (next in line)
3. The third line removes the first element of the array
4. the fourth line pushes the removed element to the end.

Then I type: `["hi", "hello", "goodbye"].next_in_line()`

Here's the error message I get when I try it:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'push' for "hi":String
```

Why doesn't my code work?

Comment: Have a look at [Array#rotate](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate) and [Array#rotate!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate-21).

Answer (score 3):

The error is because: when called without argument, `self.shift` returns the element, not an array.

To fix the error, use this:

```
class Array
  def next_in_line
    return self if empty?
    push shift
  end
end

["hi", "hello", "goodbye"].next_in_line
# => ["hello", "goodbye", "hi"]
```

Note that there's a built-in [`Array#rotate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate).

Comment: Note that this will add a `nil` element to an empty array, i.e. `[].next_in_line #=> [nil]`. You could use `push(*shift(1))` instead.

Comment: Yu, how about `class Array; def next_in_line; return self if size.zero?; push shift; end; end`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's better than mine.

Comment: Do you prefer `define_method` over `def`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Not really, I just didn't change it from OP's code, now it's `def .. end`.

Answer (score 3):

As alternative solution I will do something like:

```
class Array
  def next_in_line
    self.rotate(1)
  end

  # If you want to reverse(make Last element as First)
  def prev_in_line
    self.rotate(-1)
  end
end
array = ["hi", "hello", "goodbye"]
> array.next_in_line
#=> ["hello", "goodbye", "hi"]
> array.prev_in_line
#=> ["goodbye", "hi", "hello"]
```

Comment: You can omit `(1)`, it's the default value. You can even omit the method definition by declaring an alias: `alias_method :next_in_line, :rotate`. However, I think the OP is supposed to use `shift` and `push`.

Comment: @Stefan : Yes I understood but this was just optional solution.. instead using `shift`. Anyways Thanks for your comment about `alias_method` and `default value`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
class Array
  def next_in_line
    push(self.shift())
  end
end
```

You don't need to use `define_method` to define this instance method.  `define_method` is great for metaprogramming, but you don't need it here.

Here's how to make the code work with `define_method` for your education purposes:

```
class Array
  define_method(:next_in_line) do
    push shift
  end
end
```

Comment: You can omit `self` and `()`, i.e. `push(shift)` or `push shift`

Comment: Thanks! This worked and was as close as possible to what I needed. How would I solve this using push, shift and define_method? I tried it with define_method and it didn't work, but with def it did.

Comment: @Stefan, I hadn't noticed your comment when I posted my similar one above. (Wasn't cribbing.)

Comment: @YallaPapi - I updated my answer to show you how to solve it with `define_method`.

Comment: @Stefan - Thanks for the comment.  `push shift` looks crazy to me, but I suppose Ruby programmers love syntactic sugar to the max.